# Can we use MQTT in ROS2?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems ROS1 had MQTT bridge but nothing specific was mentioned about ROS2 in it. Can we use MQTT bridge for ros2 or is their any other way to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369262/can-we-use-mqtt-in-ros2?/) by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2021-01-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [flash_27](https://answers.ros.org/users/49272/flash_27/) on 2021-06-29**:
Hi, Have you solved this issue?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2021-06-29**:
@Flash For future readers, please add links to what you have found. My guess is you're referring to http://wiki.ros.org/mqtt_bridge as " MQTT bridge".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I didn't use the MQTT bridge, I did some workaround to receive information from the webpage I used MQTT subscribe feature but to publish info to the webpage I used the MySQL database instead of MQTT. Might not be the best method

```
from std_msgs.msg import String
import time
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from rclpy import qos
from rclpy.qos import QoSProfile
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

class SubscribeMqtt(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('subscribe_mqtt')
        State = QoSProfile(durability=qos.QoSDurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL,
                       reliability=qos.QoSReliabilityPolicy.RELIABLE, history=qos.QoSHistoryPolicy.KEEP_LAST, depth=20)
        Streaming = QoSProfile(durability=qos.QoSDurabilityPolicy.VOLATILE,
                           reliability=qos.QoSReliabilityPolicy.BEST_EFFORT, history=qos.QoSHistoryPolicy.KEEP_LAST, depth=1)
        self.declare_parameters(
            namespace='',
            parameters=[
                ('host', None),
                ('port', None)])
        self.ros2_publish = self.create_publisher(
            String, 'ros2/topic', Streaming)

        self.client = mqtt.Client()
        self.client.on_message = self.topic_get
        self.host = "hostname"
        self.port = "port"
        self.client.connect(self.host, self.port)
        self.client.subscribe("mqtt/topic", qos=1) #to subscribe more than one topic add more subscribe lines
        self.client.loop_forever()

    def topic_get(self, client, userdata, msg):
        send = String()
        topic = msg.topic
        message = msg.payload.decode("utf-8")

        if topic == "mqtt_topic":
            self.ros2_publish.publish(send)



def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    subscribe_mqtt = SubscribeMqtt()
    rclpy.spin(subscribe_mqtt)

    subscribe_mqtt.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Originally posted by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) with karma: 126 on 2021-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) on 2021-06-30**:\

> but to publish info to the webpage I used the MySQL database instead of MQTT

Just curious. Is it because you ran into issues with MQTT publishing, or because you already had SQL stuff set up and decided to go with that?

**Comment by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on 2021-06-30**:
I didn't try publishing using MQTT and also data transmitted to the webpage was too large and publishing continuously was not reliable with memory usage and also flickering behavior on the webpage. Using a database gave the frontend to freely work with incoming data and data sending to the backend was minimal and only specific calls for that only subscriber was required.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can just connect to a mqtt broker from your node code.It's not a bridge so you have to add a layer to handle the mqtt messages in ROS. (Or you can migrate the MQTT_bridge to ROS.)

---

Originally posted by [crnewton](https://answers.ros.org/users/59954/crnewton/) with karma: 71 on 2021-01-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2